# How to plot data in a web page from a free dataset which updates daily?

Tags: plotting, data-acquisition, webservices

I am using the data which is available in the links below to get data about confirmed cases for COVID-19 in Colombia. I am modeling the cumulative cases with a non linear model and all is fine. This has been made by downloading the data to work locally. I know that there are mechanisms for web development and much what I need I found in this community, except I do not know how to make the graphics update automatically from the data found in the links in a web page.

https://www.datos.gov.co/Salud-y-Protecci-n-Social/Casos-positivos-de-COVID-19-en-Colombia/gt2j-8ykr/data

https://www.datos.gov.co/w/gt2j-8ykr/dneh-mcp2?cur=i2Z4n-Qy94T&from=root

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to use [Socrata](https://dev.socrata.com) to manage the data. I have no experience with this API, but it appears you can access it using this form of the URL:

https://www.datos.gov.co/Salud-y-Protecci-n-Social/Casos-positivos-de-COVID-19-en-Colombia/gt2j-8ykr

According to the [Socrata documentation](https://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started.html), you can request this data at a particular `$offset` and `$limit` by providing these as parameters in the URL. This is a bit niche, and beyond the scope of Mathematica Stack Exchange, but this will hopefully get you started:

```
(* fetch 10 records starting from offset 0 *)
request = 
  HTTPRequest["https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json",
   <| Method -> "GET", "Query" -> {"$limit" -> 10, "$offset" -> 0}, 
    CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"|>];
response = URLExecute[request];
```

We can then query properties of the response JSON by forming an `Association`:

```
(* of our 10 records, get the first 5 cities of location *)
Association[#]["ciudad_de_ubicaci_n"] & /@ response[[1 ;; 5]]
(* {"Bogotá D.C.", "Guadalajara de Buga", "Medellín", "Medellín", "Medellín"} *)
```

If you want the total number of entries in the database (cases) then I reckon you could use the API like this `$select=count(id_de_caso)`:

```
request = 
  HTTPRequest["https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json",
   <| Method -> "GET", 
      "Query" -> {"$select" -> "count(id_de_caso)", "$offset" -> 0}, 
      CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"|>];
response = URLExecute[request];

numberOfCases = ToExpression@Values[First[response]][[1]]

(* 456689 *)
```

This matches up exactly with the data for Columbia at https://www.trackcorona.live/map as of 16th August 2020.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate the elaboration. I will begin to study it.